# Keep getting "Authorization_IdentityNotFound", "The identity of the calling application could not be established."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have created the application and used the clientid, tenantid and client secret which returns a valid token. The token appears to be valid since I do not get any authorization errors, however, when I try to do a simple call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`, I receive the error specified in the title of this question. I have set the proper API permissions.

Comment: Try here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Yep, works perfectly under graph explorer.

Comment: What permission did you add in your application? Please add a screenshot of the permissions that you added and also specify how you are getting the token with the URL.

Comment: Please also specify if you are making the call in the same tenant whose authority(https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token) is used to issue the token.